# Meanjs to serve static files

Tags: meanjs

I'm using Meanjs 0.4.1 and just for my understanding because I'm stepping into a lot of new technologies at the same time, I wish to add a new static files directory in my express.js config. I tried a lot of different configuration and still don't know how to do it. Suppose I want to create /static directory to serve files. What I have to change in my default project? Thanks!

Comment: Could you post your express.js and also what you've tried?

Comment: @feniixx As I said, I tried multiple combinations without the virtual path used by express. Adding app.use('/static', express.static(path.resolve('./static'))); below the app.use('/', express.static(path.resolve('./public'))); did what I wanted...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, I had to add app.use('/static', express.static(path.resolve('./static'))); under app.use('/', express.static(path.resolve('./public')));

For some reasons, I tried without the virtual path with no success...